# Alert me that it is already selected if i select the same option From sub-location to same option To-sub-location and same search

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
            [<div class="container" style="padding-top:70px;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Transfer Batch</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title"></label>
                        </div>
                       <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <label for="title">From Sub-location:</label>
                            <select id="from_sub_location"   class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                                <option value="0">SELECT</option>
                                <option value="1">Reception principale</option>
                                <option value="2">Reception Alle Maternite</option>
                                <option value="3">Reception Alle Pediatriqui</option>
                                <option value="4">Reception immigration</option>
                                <option value="5">Carte de credit</option>
                                <option value="6">2e etage</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <label for="title">To sub-location:</label>
                            <select id="to_sub_location"  class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                                <option value="0">SELECT</option>
                                <option value="1">Reception principale</option>
                                <option value="2">Reception Alle Maternite</option>
                                <option value="3">Reception Alle Pediatriqui</option>
                                <option value="4">Reception immigration</option>
                                <option value="5">Carte de credit</option>
                                <option value="6">2e etage</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="medicineSearchBar" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." >
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
                        <ul style="width:100%; max-height:300px; overflow-y: scroll;" id="li-psearch" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"
                            aria-labelledby="menu1">
                            <li role="presentation" class="divider-search"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card">
            <table id="myclass" class="table table-bordered">

                            <tr id="mainTable">
                                <th scope="col">From</th>
                                <th scope="col">To</th>
                                <th scope="col">Reagent Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Expiry Date</th>
                                <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                            </tr>

                            <tbody id="results_body">


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;margin: 4px 2px;">Transfer</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            @include('includes.foot')
            <meta name="loc" content="{{Session::get('loc')}}"/>

            <script>
                var countries = new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    limit: 10,
                    prefetch: {
                        // url points to a json file that contains an array of country names, see
                        // https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/gh-pages/data/countries.json
                        url: "<?=asset('assets/img/data2.json');?>",
                        // the json file contains an array of strings, but the Bloodhound
                        // suggestion engine expects JavaScript objects so this converts all of
                        // those strings
                        filter: function (list) {
                            console.log(list);
                            return $.map(list, function (country) {
                                return {name: country};
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                countries.initialize();
                $('#medicineSearchBar').typeahead(null, {
                    name: 'countries',
                    displayKey: 'name',
                    // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
                    // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
                    source: countries.ttAdapter()
                });
                jQuery('#medicineSearchBar').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum)
                {
                    //$('#extraControls').css('display','block');

                   //console.log('kl');
                    $('#results_body').append('<tr> <td scope="row">'+$('#from_location option:selected').text()+' <br>'+$('#from_sub_location option:selected').text()+'   <\/td><td scope="row">  '+$('#to_location option:selected').text()+' <br> '+$('#to_sub_location option:selected').text()+'  <\/td><td>'+datum\['name'\]+'<\/td><td>19-05-2018<\/td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty"></td><\/td></tr>');

                    //console.log($('#shipping_selector option:selected').text());

                });
            </script>
        This is data2.json 
        \["Genouillère renforcée ($30)","Genouillère Small ($20)","Genouillères XXL ($20)","Knee brace long type ($50)","Nexcare First aid Cold pack ($25)","Orthèse de stabilisation ($55)","Orthopaedic back rest long ($125)","Paire Semelle orthopodéque ($280)","Prothèse pour immobilisation ($90)","Sac de sable de 500g ($25)","Slip orthopédique ($70)"\]

        Alert me that it is already selected if i select the same option From sub-location to same option  To-sub-location and same search if it was selected before 
        eg : if i select Reception principale from From Sub-location and Reception principale from To Sub-Location and i reagent search Genouillère renforcée ($30) first time and then i again if i select Reception principale from From Sub-location and Reception principale from To Sub-Location and i reagent  search Genouillère renforcée ($30) then it should alert me that it is already selected.
        The second time when i select   select Reception principale from From Sub-location and Reception principale from To Sub-Location and i reagent search Genouillère Small ($20) then it should append all the value in the table.
If it is OK then it should append to the table . Now don't see Quantity 
and expiry Date

    This should apply for all dependent dropdown option and search list .][1] 
    This is the image of the file i have included
    Most of the script in this is jQuery.

       [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DDvT.jpg
    if want any file i will provide
```

What is the way we can implement the logic of alert if 2 dropdown and one search list  was already selected?

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @IgnacioAra  i have two dropdown  and one search bar ...in this when i select "1" from first dropdown and then i select "2" and then i select "hello" from search bar or list then it should append first time in a table below and again or second time if i followed the same data again then it should show me alert that it is already selected

Comment: Please don't dulplicate your text to avoid the posting constraints. You should really add some more context to your question.  Try to describe the problem in more detail, as currently I don't have any clue what you are trying to do by reading the text and not the code.

Comment: @Luuklag i have two dropddown and one search bar option ....in all the three field should not be same and already selected .in any one value or dropdown option changes then it should be appended

Comment: @rajeshsingh, please add that to your question using the edit button in the lower left corner.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to implement onChange listener in Jquery for your dropdown selections. Everytime dropdown changes check it with other drop down value and show alert if values are the same at any point of time.